# How to run angular 6 project locally using apache server

Tags: javascript, angular, apache

I have installed apache by using the following commands in my ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I have followed the steps from [How to install Apache server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-16-04#step-4-manage-the-apache-process) and then 
using `sudo systemctl status apache2` i have checked whether my server is running or not, and it's perfectly running.

Now in my project i have used command `ng build --prod` and get my dist folder.Then i have added `.htaccess` file inside dist folder in the same level of index.html.

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# Don't rewrite files or directories
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# Rewrite everything else to index.html
# to allow html5 state links
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Now my question is i want to run my project locally using this apache server (in the same way i do with node server). 
Where to place my dist folder and to run the apache server?

For the above question i found the answer- var/www/html.
I dit it and server run and landing page was the index.html of my project.

Now another challenge is the asserts folder inside the dist folder.And the assets folder contains another 2 folders(images and javascript). My question is where to pass the folder path so that the server will pick these folders.Remember i am trying to run my project locally in my system.Help me out please. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your dist folder is basically static website files. Just copy it's contents into Apache [documentroot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/en/mod/core.html#documentroot) and it should work.

Comment: There is no such path. i have already explored it in my ubuntu system.
`Description: Directory that forms the main document tree visible from the web
Syntax: DocumentRoot directory-path
Default: DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache/htdocs"
Context: server config, virtual host
Status: Core
Module: core`

Comment: In Ubuntu default should be /var/www/html/.

Comment: so should i put my dist folder inside this folder? its not possible to put the dist folder there there. According to your answer i should copy the content to this path. So tell me how to run my project using apache server.

Comment: Put contents of your dist folder there unless you want to add dist to url.

Comment: its not allowing me to put the contents of dist folder. plz explain it briefly. thank you

Comment: You probably don't have permissions to that folder. Look into how to use sudo.

Comment: I did it .But now again its not taking the contents of assets folder. there are another two folders inside it-images and javascript. How to run perfectly without these issues.